# Efficient Rust collector of Results holding Vecs

Tags: rust, functional-programming, iterator

I'm learning Rust, and I've come upon the following pattern which collapses an iterator of `Result<Vec<_>, _>`s to a single big `Vec<_>`, failing if any of the results from the iterator failed:

```rust
fn accumulate<T, E>(it: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Vec<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for mut ts in it {
        result.append(&mut ts?)
    }
    Ok(result)
}
```

I assume a very short "functional-style" version of this function can be written, and I'm struggling to find it. Morally, I'd like to do something like

```rust
it.map(|v| v?.into_iter()).flatten().collect()
```

but this doesn't typecheck. By running small examples, I think the point of the `flatten` there is to silently drop error results, but I'd instead like to somehow "map the `flatten` under the `Result`s". I know also that in general you couldn't collect, say, an iterator of type

```rust
impl Iterator<Item = Result<impl Iterator<Item = T>, Error>>
```

into an iterator

```rust
Result<impl Iterator<Item = impl Iterator<Item = T>>, Error>
```

since you need to have actually done all of the computations in the outer iterator in order to know the final result. Nonetheless, it seems that you can make this work in this special case, when you want to `.flatten()` and then `.collect()` right after.

Finally, I can see that that `collect()` gives me a way to build a vector of vectors from `it`, and then I could flatten this vector into the single big vector I want. But this has many needless memory allocations.

Can the standard library help you do this in an efficient, Rust-ic way?

Comment: Personally I think the imperative form is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would start with [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold), as it can deal with `Result` and stop on `Err`:

```
fn acc2<T, E>(mut it: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Vec<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    it.try_fold(
        Vec::new(),
        |mut vec, res_ts: Result<Vec<_>, E>| {
            res_ts.map(move |mut ts| { // map preserves Err
                // In case of Ok(...), append to already found elements
                vec.append(&mut ts);
                vec
            })
        }
    )
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6f738ddedecda1875df283f221dbfdc

It turns out, `Itertools` already has [`fold_results`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.fold_results) that should do what you want:

```
fn acc3<T, E>(mut it: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Vec<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    it.fold_results(
        Vec::new(),
        |mut vec, mut ts| {
            vec.append(&mut ts);
            vec
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of idiom which wasn't complex enough to have to break out into a separate function, but I'll accept this if it's the best we can do. :)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this only using iterator methods:

```
use std::iter::{self, Iterator};

pub fn accumulate<T, E>(it: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Vec<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    it.flat_map(|v| {
        v.map_or_else(
            |e| Iter::A(iter::once(Err(e))),
            |t| Iter::B(t.into_iter().map(Ok)),
        )
    })
    .collect()
}

// Utility enum that can be generated by the #[auto_enum] derive macro
enum Iter<T, A: Iterator<Item = T>, B: Iterator<Item = T>> {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}
impl<T, A: Iterator<Item = T>, B: Iterator<Item = T>> Iterator for Iter<T, A, B> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        match self {
            Self::A(a) => a.next(),
            Self::B(b) => b.next(),
        }
    }
}
```

This uses `flat_map` to yield either an iterator of `Ok`s or an iterator of an `Err` for each entry.
This is semantically equivalent to your control flow code using for loop.

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=68558e27900940476e443d670a120e91

See [`auto_enums`](https://docs.rs/auto_enums/0.7.3/auto_enums/) for deriving an enum delegating Iterator variants.

Alternatively, you can use `either::Either` in place of `Iter`, which has the same implementation for two items:

https://docs.rs/either/1.5.3/either/enum.Either.html#impl-Iterator